# CORS requests being blocked despite allowing them - CSS and JS is not being loaded [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, cors, vite

I set up a clean installation of Laravel 8 and installed bootrap via composer

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
npm install
npm run dev
```

The application is running inside a docker and is working when I insert the compiled CSS and JS bootstrap files. However, when I install them like above, I get these errors:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:5173/@vite/client. (Reason:
> CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/app.js.
> (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
>
> GET http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 0ms]

All the requested files exist and the frontend vite server is running

My config/cors.php looks like this:

```
return [

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

From my understanding, that should allow CORS requests but even after `php artisan config:clear` and restarting the container, the requests are still being blocked.

Here is the config of my Apache webserver from inside the container:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My next step would be to allow CORS in the .htaccess but I do not even know what is blocking the requests. Is it the webserver, the application or the vite server?

Comment: `'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],` doesn't seem to match the URLs in your error messages.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed it to   `'paths' => ['localhost:8080/*']` , ran the config clear and the issue persists

Comment: `localhost:8080/*` isn't a *path*. The path starts after the port number, not before the hostname. You're not even looking at the right URL, that parameter is for the paths *being read* not the origins being allowed to read from them.

Comment: I do not understand the last part, difference between _being read_ and _being allowed_ . 
`["*"]` also does not fix the issue

Comment: It's the difference between a book at a library and a human visiting the library.

Comment: Great explanation. I added **"resources/*"** and it fixed the issue. Thank you

Comment: @shutakku: Facing the same issue, i added resources/* to path but issue persists, can you share you exact path which you used. My code is as `'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'resources/*']`